# Движение картинки

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, как на JS или с помощью html сделать движение картинки при загрузке страницы?
Т.е. не по клику на нее, а что бы просто когда открывается страница картинка плавно перемещалась бы с левого верхнего угла в нижний левый (это к примеру)

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ //при загрузке страницы
    jQuery("#img").animate({left: "+=160"}, 1000); //картинка движется по горизонтали
})
```

только нужно подключить библиотеку jQuery

Comment: Движение *по диагонали* складывается из движений по горизонтали и по вертикали соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var curPosX = 0;
var curPosY = 0;
var interval;
var n = 10; // На сколько двигать за раз
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; // Ширина экрана
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; // Высота экрана
var imgWidth = 100; // Ширина картинки
var imgHeight = 100; // Высота картинки
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");

function move() {
  img1.style.left = (curPosX += n) + "px";
  img1.style.top = (curPosY += n) + "px";
  if ((curPosX == (width - imgWidth)) || (curPosY == (height - imgHeight))) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
interval = setInterval(move, 100);
```

```css
#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="">
```

Comment: Посту 3 года. Уже можно добавить вариант про CSS3.